# Smooth Follow script not working as I need it to. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed the Unity's Roll-A-Ball tutorial to get my ball moving, and the camera as well. I found the camera was not working very well so I used Unity's smooth follow script to get it moving...

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    public class SmoothFollow : MonoBehaviour
    {

        // The target we are following
        [SerializeField]
        private Transform target;
        // The distance in the x-z plane to the target
        [SerializeField]
        private float distance = 10.0f;
        // the height we want the camera to be above the target
        [SerializeField]
        private float height = 5.0f;

        [SerializeField]
        private float rotationDamping;
        [SerializeField]
        private float heightDamping;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start() { }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void LateUpdate()
        {
            // Early out if we don't have a target
            if (!target)
                return;

            // Calculate the current rotation angles
            var wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
            var wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;

            var currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
            var currentHeight = transform.position.y;

            // Damp the rotation around the y-axis
            currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

            // Damp the height
            currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);

            // Convert the angle into a rotation
            var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentRotationAngle, 0);

            // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
            // distance meters behind the target
            transform.position = target.position;
            transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;

            // Set the height of the camera
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x ,currentHeight , transform.position.z);

            // Always look at the target
            transform.LookAt(target);
        }
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't really work the way I need it to. It keeps spun out sort of, and makes it very confusing to tell where you going ([take a look at this video I uploaded, and watch the key presses](https://vid.me/xHLA)) . What I want the camera to do is follow behind the player (the ball) at all times. When I go left it should stay behind me as I turn, and when I go backwards it should turn around to be at the back of the ball. So how would I do this?

Comment: The script works as intended, think of it as if the camera where attached to the ball with an string, until the string doesn't pulls the camera it doesn't corrects it's angle. If you want your camera to look forward and stay back of the object calculate the movement normal, reverse it, multiply it by a fixed distance, add this vector to the object's position and place the camera in the resulting vector. Beware, if the object is not moving then you must conserve the current movement normal.

Comment: Try to freeze y-rotation of your ball

Comment: In fact two rotations, except the one from which you want to rotate